# Trigger navigation to another route with Admin-on-rest/ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

What's the correct way to trigger navigation to another route on button click for example? My current solution is to set `window.location` to the route I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the withRouter HOC from react router with a custom button: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter